# Python Discount function based on input

Tags: python, python-3.x, discount

I am trying to create a Python program that calculates the discount you receive on books based on how many you purchase (the books are being called 'book 1', 'book 2', etc for this and saved in a list). The program should take your input (example: book 1, book 2)
There is no discount if the same book is purchased twice, but if 2 or more different books are purchased there is a  a single copy of any of the five books costs 8 EUR

- a 5% discount is applied if two different books from the series are purchased
- a 10% discount is applied if three different books from the series are purchased
- a 20% discount is applied if four different books from the series are purchased
- a 25% discount is applied if all five books from the series are purchased
- if the customer purchases two copies of one book, the second copy will cost 8 EUR and will not have any discount applied unless there are more duplicated of another book that could have a discount applied as part of a second set of books.

my code is below, not sure where I am going wrong as I am running into a lot of syntax errors and I don't think I have all the information that's needed.

```
#list of books
books = ["book 1", "book 2", "book 3", "book 4", "book 5"]
if books <= 1
    print("One book is 8 EURO - no discount")
elif books <= 2
    books discount =books*0.05
elif books <= 3
    books discount =books*0.10
elif books <= 4
    books discount =books*0.20
elif books <= 5
    books discount =books*0.25

print("Discount : ",discount)
print("Total cost  : ",price -discount)

else:
print("no discount if two books of the same title are purchased")
```

Comment: 1. Your list just contains string values, consider using a dictionary instead so you can seperate the values, or just use a list with the values only, like [1, 2, 3], or if you want the amount of books, use len().
2. your print statements are referring to vars you've never set up.
3. your vars must be one word without spaces, so "books discount" doesn't work.

try those three things first and you should be there, or very close

Comment: I would highly suggest you look at a basic python tutorial first and I think many of your syntax issues will be solved. Some nice links for you [link](https://www.learnpython.org/) [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm) and [link](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-tutorial-step-by-step/)

Comment: First of all, please read about [ask]. *Not sure where I'm going wrong* is not exactly a problem statement. If you have any errors - post them. If your output is wrong - show it and what you expect it to be. Second, it seems like you should go over some basic tutorial, and might want to start with [the official one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). For starters, `books discount` should probably be `books_discount`. You can't have spaces in names

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def discount_rule(booklist, price):
    discount_rates = [0, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25]
    different_books = len(set(booklist))
    discount = discount_rates[different_books]
    discount_amount = discount * price;
    discounted_price = price - discount_amount;
    return {"grandTotal": len(books) * discounted_price,
            "discount": discount_amount,
            "book_price": price - discounted_price
            "books" : different_books
    }

  
#list of books
books = ["book 1", "book 2", "book 3", "book 4", "book 5"]
unit_price = 8
cash = discount_rule(books, unit_price)

if cash['books'] == 1:
    print ("One book is {} EURO - no discount".format(unit_price))
print("Discount : ", cash["discount"])
print("Total cost  : ", cash["grandTotal"])
if len(books) > cash["books"]:
    print("no discount if two books of the same title are purchased")
```

Beware, not tested, you have to find bugs, but I hope it will set you in the course of a viable solution

Answer (score 1):

**Give it a try**

```
books =["book 1", "book 2", "book 3", "book 4", "book 5"]
price = 8

nos = len(books)
purchase = []
tDiscount = 0
tPrice = 0

for i in range(1, nos+1):
    print("Enter quantity of book ", i, ": ")
    num = int(input())
    if num == 0:
        tDiscount += 0
        print(" Price: 0\n Discount: 0\n")
    elif num == 1:
        print(" One book is 8 EURO - no discount\n Price: ", price, "\n")
        tPrice += price
    elif num == 2:
        tDiscount += price * 0.05
        print(" Price: ", num * price, "\n Discount : ", price * 0.05, "\n")
        tPrice += (num * price)
    elif num == 3:
        tDiscount += price * 0.10
        print(" Price: ", num * price, "\n Discount : ", price * 0.10, "\n")
        tPrice += (num * price)
    elif num == 4:
        tDiscount += price * 0.20
        print(" Price: ", num * price, "\n Discount : ", price * 0.20, "\n")
        tPrice += num * price
    else:
        tDiscount += price * 0.25
        print(" Price: ", num * price, "\n Discount : ", price * 0.25, "\n")
        tPrice += (num * price)

print("\nBill: ", tPrice, "\nDiscount: ", tDiscount, "\nTotal Bill: ", tPrice - tDiscount)
```

**I hope you find it helpful**